# Profiler for a Grails Application

Tags: grails, profiler

Are there any tools that can identify the total memory usage, cpu, and other information on resources of a specific grails web application deployed in a Tomcat server?

Also, if my grails app is using Quartz plugin, can anyone tell me how to profile a specific job instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I am using a bunch of tools for profiling and monitoring my own grails application. Here are the plugins/tools that help me to achieve this and work without any problems:

1. **[JavaMelody plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-melody)** : this tool is a **must-have**. Just install the plugin and go to */myapp/monitoring* and you're done. You'll get all information you need on cpu, mem usage, sql queries, http errors...It should be enough for your needs described in your question
2. [**Application Info plugin**](http://grails.org/plugin/app-info) : this very recent plugin is very useful and almost indispensable. It gives you various info about your application status. For your concerns, you will have access to graphs describing memory usage, information about sessions (opened or closed), detailed information on every aspect of your hibernate layer (cache, tables, entities...). Above all, this plugin is developped and supported by Burt Beckwith, member of SpringSource team.
3. **[Perf4j plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/perf4j)** : This plugin helps you collecting performance statistics with minimal effort. I am using it but it has better use whe tuning your application

You can also use other plugins/tools like : [p6spy](http://www.grails.org/plugin/p6spy) (for logging of SQL queries), [Grails Audit Logging plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/audit-logging) (for tracking changes of domain objects) or [Profiler plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/profiler) for which I can guarantee that they work correctly (not the case for all plugins!).

All of these plugins you can find by tag [performance](http://grails.org/plugins/tag/performance) in Grails plugins portal

I hope it helps.

Comment: FYI: I have had issues with Jasper Reports and Melody not working too well together. I don't remember the details but I had to uninstall the plugin for Jasper Reports to work again.

Comment: I never used Jasper Reports, I didn't mention Jasper Reports and I don't understand why you talk about Jasper Reports ? Concerning Java Melody, it works wonderfully for me.

Comment: thanks for the list! i just tested melody and app-info, they look very promising. now, i just need to get familiar with them. again, thanks a lot!

Comment: The link to the Java Meldody Plugin seems outdated/wrong. This one looks more up to date: http://grails.org/plugin/grails-melody

Answer (score 2):

Here is some useful articles about performance tuning:

- [Tune the performance of Grails apps](http://grails.github.io/grails-howtos/en/performanceTuning.html)
- [GR8Conf 2011: Tuning Grails Applications by Peter Ledbrook](http://www.slideshare.net/gr8conf/gr8conf-2011-tuning-grails-applications-by-peter-ledbrook)
- [Profiling Grails Applications With VisualVM](http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/01/25/profiling-grails-applications-with-visualvm/)

Answer (score 0):

http://grails.org/Profiler+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

The profiler plugin that MTH mentions only gives you timing info for various parts of the Grails app.  For monitoring resource usage, you're better off using JMX; here are a couple of links that should help.

- [Tomcat monitoring with JMX](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html)
- [Grails JMX plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jmx)