# Grails DB performance H2 vs MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, grails, h2

I am currently using out of the box H2 file stored DB in order to test my Grails (2.1.0) application. I have 4 domain classes with about 20 field total. It is a small application.

Recently I noticed that once I passed 14000 records (H2 file DB), Grails application started to work slower - CPU utilization is considerably higher and record insertion seems to become sluggish. Note: I have up to 250 Threads inserting data. Above situation made me ask following questions:

1. Does MySQL perform better than H2?
2. How can I test Grails app and clearly show/prove that slowness comes from H2 interactions? I don't want to simply relay on my own observations.
3. Can someone elaborate on use of H2 in Grails project? I want to know where is "cut off" point of using H2 and it is time to move to MySQL? --Perhaps I am abusing H2 it with so many records.

Thank you.

Comment: do you have 250 threads inserting records at around the same time?

Comment: Yes, all at the same time. More over I perform FindBy operation right before each insertion, search is done on String field - non-indexed.

Comment: perhaps 14000 records is the point where H2 is unable to hold the table in memory and does a full table scan paging from disk rather than just in memory ... try adding an index to that string field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance problems can have many reasons. It is true that MySQL has more advanced mechanisms for large databases (gigabytes of data) and concurrency (many concurrent connections).

But for such a small database (14000 records?), I think the problem is somewhere else, very likely related to the application, and not the database. What I would do is [analyze what the problem](http://h2database.com/html/performance.html) is. It could be a missing index or similar.

Comment: Code works flawlessly until I am starting to reach > 14K records. Do I need to specify index in domain class? I figured it is automatically done.

Comment: After reviewing code I have side question:

Can slowness be because I do search on String field in DB? I do lots of them.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. H2 doesn't have a very smart pattern matcher, it is slow for very large strings. I guess you could use a profiler to find out where H2 spends most of the time.

Comment: I believe I found the issue. You were right, it is not DB related. I tested write/read speed and it very quick. My issue is else where.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might find some of the answer on '[Profiler for a Grails Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395167/profiler-for-a-grails-application)' useful in getting some data on the application performance before you make any changes.